# How many publications are required to get a postdoc in plant science?

Tags: publications, postdocs

It is my humble question to all of you: how many publications are required to get a postdoc in plant science? I have seen researchers with plenty of publications not get any postdoctoral funding, but one of my seniors got it with only one publication (that too in a MDPI journal).
I am utterly confused.

Comment: The CVs of people who got jobs like the ones you want are the most reliable source of information.  Ignore the advice of people who are not familiar with your field and personal goals.

Answer (score 1):

There is more involved in hiring at any level, including postdoc positions, than simply counting publications. It is a judgement call by those hiring as to how a candidate will "fit" a position and an institution.

So, in any field, the answer is somewhere between zero and a huge number, depending on how things are weighed. Even seemingly insubstantial things such as "This is a friendly and easy to get along with person" can make the difference.

Zero publications might actually occur if a committee sees a late draft of a remarkable dissertation - likely to be published, and with interesting research ideas going forward.

Research potential is probably more important in most decisions than research history, though. But a good history indicates potential, of course, especially in an early career person. Not infallibly, however.